# set values for many2one child fields by function?

Tags: python, xml, function, odoo

Below is my view xml and model class. I have a form to add records, and it works properly.
But I need to set values for that sub childs onchange event.
I refer this link also from [documentation](http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/03_module_dev_03/?highlight=onchange).

And here is my whole code of the module [GIT HUB REPO](https://github.com/priyankahdp/openerp):

```
<field name='selected_tea_workers_line_ids' nolabel='1'>
<tree string='List' readonly='1'>
<field name='tea_line_worker_id' invisible="0" />
<field name='worker_id' />
<field name='is_selected' />
</tree>
</field>

    def on_change_division(self, cr, uid, ids, bpl_division_id):
        v = {}
        if bpl_division_id:
            work_offer = self.pool.get('bpl.work.offer').browse(cr, uid, 2)
            v['selected_tea_workers_line_ids'] = work_offer.selected_tea_workers_line_ids
            if work_offer.selected_tea_workers_line_ids:
                for record_item in work_offer.selected_tea_workers_line_ids:
                    v['tea_line_worker_id'] = record_item.selected_tea_workers_line_ids.tea_line_worker_id
                    v['worker_id'] = record_item.selected_tea_workers_line_ids.worker_id
                    v['is_selected'] = record_item.selected_tea_workers_line_ids.is_selected
        return {'value':v}
```

Here is the idea: if I select company -> division -> then need to load all workers (as a list.they have their name & works) related to that division.

Below, I added sample pic

[image]

**GOT THE ANSWER**

```
def on_change_division(self, cr, uid, ids, division_id):
    v = {}
    list_data = []
    if division_id:
        worker_ids = self.pool.get('bpl.worker').search(cr, uid, [('bpl_division_id', '=', division_id)])
        for record in self.pool.get('bpl.worker').browse(cr, uid, worker_ids):
            list_data.append({'worker_id': record.id})
        v['selected_tea_workers_line_ids'] = list_data
        return {'value':v}
```

Credits need to go for [user1576199](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1576199/user1576199)

Comment: hi anne means you want to set value in one2many fields on change of division

Comment: yeah exactly..please help me to sort this issue

if u want refer above mentioned Git Hub repo

Comment: please sent me your module

Comment: now its sent to ur gmail.please refer the attached zip file

refer line 217 in model class

Comment: we can discuss this issue on chat

Comment: ok how to go for chat.?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27158/discussion-between-anne-mary-and-user1576199)

Comment: please close this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got confused in your code, i can not understand what is the login behind this code. what are you trying to do

but i will show you one example how to set value in one2many field from on change function

```
def on_change_code_id(self, cr, uid, ids, code_id, context=None):

    list_lines = []
    result = {'value': {}}
    req_obj = self.pool.get('code.requisition')

    data = req_obj.browse(cr, uid, code_id)

    for line in data.line_ids:
        list_lines.append({'product_id': line.product_id.id or False,
                           'product_qty': line.product_qty or 0,
                           'name': line.product_id.name,
                           'product_uom': line.product_uom_id.id,
                           'date_planned': time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                        })

    result['value']['order_line'] = list_lines

    return result
```

here in the code you see, we have to return list of dicts to set value in one2many you have to give all required values of one2many object fields. hope this help

Comment: how to call that fields to set data.?
like this ?
selected_tea_workers_line_ids.tea_line_worker_id.seems ur code complex.where we give command to set data to out fields

refer line 217 in bpl.py

Comment: I want this odoo 11. Please explain